# Add new property to Prototype using contructor argument

Tags: javascript, prototype

If I have:

```
function Person(name, age){
   this.name = name;
   this.whoIs = function(){
        alert('I am ' + this.name);
   }
}
var john = new Person('John');
john.whoIs();
```

all will work and I will get a nice alert with: "I am John".

Is there a way to add method to the prototype after the constructor and that will have access to the constructor arguments?

Something like:

```
function Person(name, age){
   this.name = name;
   this.whoIs = function(){
        alert('I am ' + this.name);
   }
}
Person.prototype.age = Person.arguments[1];
var john = new Person('John', 20);
john.age; // would give 20
```

Is there a way to do this? Ie: being able to add a property or method to a prototype that will have access to the arguments when a new instance is created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to have a dynamic property in the prototype. See the prototype as the blueprint of your object.

You *can* do this:

```
function Person(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.whoIs = function(){
        alert('I am ' + this.name);
    }
    this.age = age;
}
var john = new Person('John', 20);
john.age; // would give 20
```

---

Also, the `whoIs` function is added for each `Person` object. You can add it to the prototype instead:

```
function Person(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
Person.prototype.whoIs = function () {
    return 'I am ' + this.name;
}
var john = new Person('John', 20);
john.whoIs(); // would give "I am John"
```

Comment: You can't. `this` is only handle to the data you have. You can't reach values yet when you're defining the prototype. You could make a language that does this, but you can wonder about how useful it is. You can also solve it with a private variable by the way. JavaScript kinda-sorta supports private variables. Most editors will pick it up if you annotate.